# syntax highlighting for javadoc?

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, javadoc

Currently I format code examples in my javadoc using the PRE tag e.g.:

```
/**
 * Example javadoc
 * 
<pre>
String foo = "bar";
</pre>
 *
 * @return   true if the operation completed
 */
```

But this turns out rather monotone and boring in the resulting javadoc, I'd much rather have some syntax highlighting similar to [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to get it done using the [beautyOfCode](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/beautyofcode-jquery-plugin-for-syntax-highlighting/) plugin.  I'm not sure if there's an easy way to hook into the javadoc generation, but after-the-fact you can just do the following in your header:

```
$(function(){  
    $("pre").beautifyCode('java');  
});
```

and all text inside PRE tags will be highlighted as java.  Check out the links above for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [`pegdown-doclet`](https://github.com/Abnaxos/pegdown-doclet), which lets you use Github-style fenced code blocks.

````
```java
public static class Example {}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here all work, but introduce additional dependencies or add additional build complexity. If you're using Maven to generate the docs, and want the simplest way to get this to work with no extra files or dependencies, then add to the `maven-javadoc-plugin` config:

```
<additionalOptions>-html5 --allow-script-in-comments</additionalOptions>
<header><![CDATA[
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/styles/vs.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
]]></header>
```

The full plugin configuration will look something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalOptions>-html5 --allow-script-in-comments</additionalOptions>
        <nohelp>true</nohelp>
        <show>private</show>
        <header><![CDATA[
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/styles/vs.min.css">
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
        ]]></header>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

[Pick your theme from here](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) and replace the "vs" above with the theme you like (all lower case w/ dashes between words, so like `mono-blue`; if the one you want isn't working, you can look [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/highlight.js) for a list of available files).

Then write your examples like this:

```
 /**
  * Does something cool.
  * <pre><code class="java">{@code
      // some example code here
      int x = 5;
  * }</code></pre>
  */
```

https://burningmime.gitlab.io/setmatch/javadoc/com/burningmime/setmatch/RuleDB.html

EDIT: You don't actually need the class in `<pre><code class="java">`. You can modify that javascript bit so that you don't need to change the source files at all, and anything in the `{@code}` parts will get highlighted, since Javadoc already adds the `<code>` tag. I don't know enough JavaScript to do that, but it shouldn't be too hard. That solution is probably the least invasive of all, since it would just be a couple lines in the build config.

I'm marking this community wiki, so if someone wants to come along and add that, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507476/maven-javadoc-how-to-include-centralized-resources/) by me explains - despite its title - how to add syntax highlighting feature to your Javadocs using SyntaxHighlighter as the OP requests.

The answer assumes you're using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) but it has the benefit that *all* your projects will automatically inherit the ability to do syntax highlighting in Javadoc. You'll *not* have to do this for each and every project. With this recipe there's nothing you need to do in each project to have the feature.

Additionally this is the same mechanism you would use if you wanted to do style customizations (i.e. how your Javadoc looks).

Answer (score 1):

Found this question looking for something else. In the interim I wrote a tool that embeds gist samples into JavaDoc in: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/javadoc-source-samples-that-dont-suck.html

You can see this used in our code e.g.:
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/MediaPlayer.html

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/package-summary.html