# KDoc: Insert code snippet

Tags: documentation, kotlin, kdoc

How do I insert a code snippet in KDoc, Kotlin's default documentation tool?

In Java, I can use the following:

```
/**
 * Example usage:
 *
 * <pre>
 * <code>&#64;JavaAnnotation
 * public void foo() {
 *     // Code
 * }
 * </code>
 * </pre>
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface JavaAnnotation {}
```

There seems to be no equivalent in Kotlin. I tried using Markdown, but inserting 2 spaces after line end does not line-break.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use triple backticks:

````
/**
 * Example usage:
 *
 * ```
 * @JavaAnnotation
 * public void foo() {
 *     // Code
 * }
 * ```
 */
````

Comment: Tilde (`~~~`) works, too. It might be easier to type.