# How to write tags in a Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I would like to comment an example tag syntax in a javadoc.
But Javadoc doesn't display Tags in its comment.
Is it possible to do this ?

Sample: the svg tag comment is not displayed, because javadoc interpretes the tags not as comment.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param sMapData contains tags like the following sample : <br>
 * <svg><text color="000000" dates="-626,100;-545,100" fontsize="8" fs="normal" id="text31757_i1a" opa="1" text="L y d i a n" x="2915.5793" y="1889.9111"/></svg>
 * @return
 */
```

Comment: Have a look here [Multiple line code example in Javadoc comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/542142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542142) to *Multiple line code example in Javadoc comment* you can use `{@code }` wrapped in `<pre></pre>`:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param sMapData contains tags like the following sample:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * <svg>
 *   <text color="000000" dates="-626,100;-545,100" fontsize="8" fs="normal" id="text31757_i1a" opa="1" text="L y d i a n" x="2915.5793" y="1889.9111"/>
 * </svg>
 * }
 * </pre>
 * @return
 */
```

Comment: Thanks you very much ! I didn't realize that documenting code makes fun, but it does :-)