# How can I preven IntelliJ's JavaDoc formatting from removing my indentations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Here is a javadoc comment that I wrote:

```
  /**
   * This utility allows the user to do the following.
   * <ul>
   *   <li>A cool feature</li>
   *   <li>Another cool feature</li>
   * </ul>
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Here is the same comment, reformatted by intelliJ

```
  /**
   * This utility allows the user to do the following.
   * <ul>
   * <li>A cool feature</li>
   * <li>Another cool feature</li>
   * </ul>
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
```

How can I prevent the autoformat feature from clobbering my intentations?

---

In order to prevent IntelliJ from removing my newlines, I checked a box:

> Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Preseve Line Feeds

I wish there was a "Preseve leading whitespace" box in the same place, but there isn't.

Comment: Try advice from this answer https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90692#comment=27-373981

Comment: Actually, whitespace/indent removal applies to anything in Javadocs for IntellJ. For example, if you have `<code></code>` fragment with properly indented source code inside Javadocs, IntelliJ wipes spaces out. Upvote for "reserve leading whitespaces" checkbox.

Comment: Googling helped for my `<code></code>` case - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542142/441652). IntelliJ does not remove whitespaces if `@code` tag is used. But this HTML case still remains as it's not part of code but rich text formatting.