# How to format javadoc in intelliJ

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I'm trying to describe a json object structure in a javadoc and it shows just fine until I format the code, which flattens the javadoc content.

How it looks when typing (And how I want it to look at the end):

```
/**
 * A configuration blah blah blah
 * KBA : {
 *     ...
 *     crossReferences: {
 *         IS : "happy",
 *         SJ : "sad"
 *     }
 * }
 * @param value The value of the current node
 */
```

How it looks after formatting (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L`):

```
/**
 * A configuration blah blah blah
 * KBA : {
 * ...
 * crossReferences: {
 * IS : "happy",
 * SJ : "sad"
 * }
 * }
 * @param value The value of the current node
 */
```

Comment: wrapping your code with a `<pre>` tag doesn't do the trick ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541920/multiple-line-code-example-in-javadoc-comment

Comment: @n00dl3 Thanks! It worked.